# Compiling and running in different containers

Tags: docker

I have a project which compiles to a binary file, and running that binary file exposes some REST APIs.

To compile the project I need docker image A which has the compiler and and all the libraries required to produce the executable. To run the executable (ie. host the service) I can get away with a much smaller image B (just basic linux distro, no need for the compiler).

How does one use docker is such a situation?

Comment: You can use a simple script that runs a container with the source code in a volume to build it and then copys the executable and builds the image, but Docker can not do that in one step

Comment: Depends on your build chain. If you do it without any other external tooling.. i would go with a mounted host volume where the source code is located, run the build and backe the binary into a run image.

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir local_dir
docker run -dv $PWD/local_dir:/mnt BUILD_CONTAINER
```

compile code and save it to /mnt in the container.  It'll be written to local_dir on your host filesystem and persist after the container is destroyed.

You Should now write a Dockerfile and add a step to copy in the new binary, then build.  But for example's sake...

```
docker run -dv $PWD/local_dir:/mnt PROD_CONTAINER
```

Your bin, and everything else in local_dir, will reside in the container at `/mnt/`

Answer (score 1):

My thinking for this scenario is that you can prepare two base images:

- The 1st one, which includes compiler and all libs for building your executable, call it `base-image:build`
- The 2nd one, as the base image to build your final image to delivery, call it `base-image:runtime`

And then  break your build process into two steps:

- Step 1: build your executable inside `base-image:build`, and then put your `executable` to some place, like NFS or any registry from where you can fetch it for later use;
- Step 2: write your `Dockerfile` which `FROM base-image:runtime`, fetch your artifact/executable from wherever generated by Step 1, `docker build` your delivery image, and then `docker push` to your registry for release.

Hope this could be helpful :-)